# One Component - different logic each call

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I'm new to lightning - so I hope this is not a stupid question -

I want to create a button component - the reason I want to create it as a component is to display some messages as Toast and create a nice design for all the buttons in my Projects.

Let's say I want to create two buttons - Save and Cancel from a container component.

And I want to perform an apex handle to save.

I want to know - how can I achieve different controllers with different logic to handle the Save event?

And in other words: how Can I achieve different apex handling for each container that calls the button component?

for example :

Container Component "A" - Call two times to the Button component - one as cancel and one as save.
And it needs to save some changes that made in contact.

Container Component "B" in a Different Project - Call two times to the Button component - one as cancel and one as save.
And it needs to save some changes that made in Opportunity.

One of the reasons to create components is to reuse them in the same projects or different.

I know that I need to write what I tried and did...

I just want a direction to the best practice of using the Lightning Component and how to do it right with my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use different action handlers for button clicks that will fire javascript controller methods, and these in return will send the parameters to the server side controller.

Your apex controller depending on the attributes or method parameters you are sending, can handle each action differently (different parameters for example).

You can check sample gallery apps for best practices on lightning development [here.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/sample-gallery)

If you elaborate and be more specific in your use case scenario, other community members can also have easier time answering your question.